# Google Maps API - Only One JS Script Displays on Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, infowindow, infobox

I answered my question with help from a friend - labels and building polygons with pop ups now display.

The code uses an external GeoJSON with two building coordinates, values for colors and building names.  The GeoJSON is used to draw the buidling polygons, and populate infoBox window.

The labels are blank window boxes with coordinates and text hard coded.  There are other examples of this on Stack Overflow, however, I was having trouble getting both functions to work.  Thanks to everyone who helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UT Campus Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 90%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
    <script>

        // global variable
        var map;
        var mapData; 
        var dataURL = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B9SE53Gvj0AsR3hyUDJ4Nk9ybG8/Bld.json';

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var colors = ["#9295ca", "#076bb6", "#e66665", "#666", "#333", "#456789"];

        // create the map when the page loads
        function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.284, -97.7325)
            };

            // build the map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

            // get the data and draw the polygons
            $.getJSON( dataURL, function( data ) {
                loadGeoJSON(data);
            });

            // add colors
            stylePolygons();

            // add click listeners with info boxes
            addClickListeners();

            // finally add labels
            addLabels();
        };

        // fetch the geojson data from the server
        function loadGeoJSON (data) {
            console.log(data);
            map.data.addGeoJson(data,{idPropertyName:"id"});
        };

        // assign colors based on value property of each feature
        function stylePolygons () {
            map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
                var value = feature.getProperty('value');
                var color = colors[value];
                return {
                    fillColor: color,
                    strokeWeight: 1
                };
            });
        };

        //listen for click events
        function addClickListeners () {
            map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
                //show an infowindow on click   
                infoWindow.setContent('<div style="line-height:1.35;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"> <b>'+event.feature.getProperty("bldAbbrev") +"</b>"+"</br>" + event.feature.getProperty("GoogInfoWi") +"<br/>" + event.feature.getProperty("addressStr") +"</div>");
                var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
                anchor.set("position",event.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(map,anchor);

            });
        };

        function buildMarkers(map, markerData) {
            var newMarkers = [],
                marker;
                var blankMarker = {
                    path: 'M 0,0,0 z',
                    fillColor: 'yellow',
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                    scale: 0,
                    strokeColor: 'white',
                    strokeWeight: 4
                };
            for(var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: blankMarker,
                    draggable: true,
                    position: markerData[i].latLng,
                    visible: true
                }),
                boxText = document.createElement("div"),
                //these are the options for all infoboxes
                infoboxOptions = {
                     content: boxText,
                    disableAutoPan: false,
                    maxWidth: 0,
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(40, 0),
                    zIndex: null,
                    boxStyle: {
                        background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                        opacity: 1,
                        width: "24px"
                    },
                    closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
                    closeBoxURL: "",
                    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
                    isHidden: false,
                    pane: "floatPane",
                    enableEventPropagation: false
                };

                newMarkers.push(marker);
                //define the text and style for all infoboxes
                boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 8px; background:#0xFFFFFF; color:#333; font-family:Arial; font-size:24px; padding: 0px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-border-radius:0px; -moz-border-radius:0px;";
                boxText.innerHTML = markerData[i].label;
                //Define the infobox
                newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
                //Open box when page is loaded
                newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, marker);

            }
            return newMarkers;
        };

        function addLabels () {
            var markerInfoArray = 
            [
                { 
                    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(30.2848878, -97.7362857), 
                    label:"SAC"
                },
                { 
                    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(30.2819835, -97.7404576),
                    label:"ATT"
                }
            ];

            var markerArray = buildMarkers(map, markerInfoArray);
        };



        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the combined code that doesn't work look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've updated the scripts with the current versions that are encountering errors.  Thank you!

Comment: Your JSON doesn't seem to be publicly available, can you either make it publicly available or even better put enough in your question to reproduce the problem (so your question contains a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and isn't dependent on external links).

Comment: I've cleaned up the code.  Now working to hard code in a few polygons and remove need for external GeoJSON link.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the original question with the working code.  Sorry for poor formatting and procedure, this was my first question.